# How to properly show in the frontend the checkboxes checked or not based on what is stored in DB?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that has some questions/fields (email, phone number,...) and then the user can select if that field should be included for the registration types that exist for a conference and also if that field should be mandatory or not for each registration type, through checkboxes.

Based on the selected checkboxes the info is inserted in the pivot table "registration_type_questions" that has this structure: registration_type_id, question_id, required.

The database is like this for now:

```
registration_type_id  question_id  required
    2                   1          1    (include quetion 1 in rt02 and is mandatory)
    1                   2          1    (include quetion 2 in rt01 and is mandatory)
    1                   1          1    (include quetion 1 in rt01 and is mandatory)
```

**Doubt**

I want to show in the frontend the checkboxes checked or not based on what is in the db. Do you know how is possible to check the checkboxes on the frontend based on this db values?

With that db info the frontend should appear like below:

[image]

**Form:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Questions</th>
        <th scope="col">Include for registration type</th>
        <th scope="col">Mandatory</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($question as $q)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$q->question}}</td>
            <td>
                @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input autocomplete="off" name="include[{{ $q->id }}][{{ $rtype->id }}]" class="form-check-input {{$rtype->name}}" type="checkbox" value="1" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            {{$rtype->name}}
                        </label>
                    </div>

                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input autocomplete="off"  name="mandatory[{{ $q->id }}][{{ $rtype->id }}]"
                               class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"
                        </label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Question Model**

```
class Question extends Model
{

    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_type_questions');
    }
}
```

**Registration type model**

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'registration_type_questions');
    }
}
```

**Conferece model**

```
class Conference extends Model
{
   // A conference has many registration types
    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller store the relation values to variables and pass it to the view.

```
foreach($question as $ques) {
    foreach($ques->registration_type as $regType) {
        $optional[$ques->id][$regType->id] = 1;

        if($regType->pivot->required == 1) {
            $required[$ques->id][$regType->id] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

pass`$optional` and `required` to the view. with the `$question`.

In your view check whether the current checkbox has relation defined in the varible then make the checkbox property "**checked**".

```
@foreach($question as $q)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$q->question}}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input autocomplete="off" name="include[{{ $q->id }}][{{ $rtype->id }}]" 
                        class="form-check-input {{$rtype->name}}" type="checkbox" value="1" id="{{$rtype->id}}" {{ !empty($optional[$q->id][$rtype->id]) ? "checked" : "" }}>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                        {{$rtype->name}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input autocomplete="off"  name="mandatory[{{ $q->id }}][{{ $rtype->id }}]"
                       class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" id="{{$rtype->id}}" {{ !empty($required[$q->id][$rtype->id]) ? "checked" : "" }}>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"</label>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working properly. In the database both questions that exist for now (email and phone) and required for both registration types that exist for now(general and plus). But in the frontend only the registration type "plus" checkboxes are being checked.

Comment: I have in QuestionController the edit method that returns the view, and Im passing to the view like: return view('questions.edit')
            ->with('conference', $conference)
            ->with('registration_types', $registrationTypes)
            ->with('registration_types_names', $registrationTypeName)
            ->with('question', $question)
            ->with('optional', $optional)
            ->with('required', $required);

Comment: This: array:2 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▼
    2 => 1
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    2 => 1
  ]
]

Comment: Thanks again, it's working!! Can you just explain this foreach? I'm not understanding properly how is working. " foreach($ques->registration_type as $regType) {
        $optional[$ques->id][$regType->id] = 1;

        if($regType->pivot->required == 1) {
            $required[$ques->id][$regType->id] = 1;
        }
    }".

Comment: using the foreach loop the exact copy of your db is copied to the 2 dimensional arrays `optional` and `required`. array  `$optional[question_id][registration_type_id]`is created in this format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167422/discussion-between-ab-in-and-johnz).

Answer (score 0):

Add or remove the `checked` property depending on the DB value.

```
@foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
  <div class="form-check">
      <input autocomplete="off"
             name="include[{{ $q->id }}][{{ $rtype->id }}]" 
             class="form-check-input {{$rtype->name}}" 
             type="checkbox" 
             id="{{$rtype->id}}"
             {{ array_search($rtype->id, $q->registration_type->pluck('id')->all()) !== FALSE
                ? 'checked' : '' }}>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        {{$rtype->name}}
      </label>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

For the sake of performance, you may have `$q->registration_type->pluck('id')->toArray()` prepared from the controller, so you won't have to run those functions for each registration type.

Comment: Thanks it's working for the registration types checkboxes, do you know also how to do for the mandatory checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

In your form you will need to add:

```
<input autocomplete="off"  
       name="mandatory[{{ $q->id }}][{{ $rtype->id }}]"
       class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" 
       type="checkbox" 
       value="1" 
       id="{{$rtype->id}}"
       {{$rtype->required==1?" checked":""}}>
```

You realise that non-ticked radio/checkboxs do not get submitted with the form. This means that you need to check their existance first (isset).

Another problem that I noticed. In the data example that you have given, when you update `registration_type_id` of 1 which record will it update (the code for this might be elsewhere an not supplied).

Comment: Thanks, sorry, but I don't properly. Relative to first point, the user can see which checkboxes are checked and change based on he wants and the submit the form. The other point, I don't understand what is the problem. Can you explain better?